# Cpp Iterators usage with next in list of pairs

Tags: c++, iterator, bubble-sort

probably easy question:

I am trying to iterate a list of pairs, get string time to time_t and then compare them to be sorted (bubble sort).

However, using next() on iterator give me segmentation fault on last result and kill my program.

How can I prevent this?

```cpp
   list<pair<string, Vehicle*>>::iterator it;
    for (list<pair<string, Vehicle*>>::iterator it = allVehicle.begin(); it != allVehicle.end(); ++it ) {
        time_t time1 = get_the_real_time(it->second->get_date(), it->second->get_time_in());
        cout << time1 << endl;

        // auto next_it = next(it, 1);
        time_t time2 = get_the_real_time(next(it, 1)->second->get_date(), next(it, 1)->second->get_time_in());
    }
```

Result:

```sh
1031729120470
1031729123045
1031732680046
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I supose that the last round I tries to access a element which do not exist, but I don't know how can I prevent that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not dereference the end iterator. You can stop the loop when `next(it,1)` is the end iterator:

```
auto n = next(it, 1);
if (n == allVehicle.end()) break;
time_t time2 = get_the_real_time(n->second->get_date(), n->second->get_time_in());
```

or rather adjust the loop condition:

```
for (auto it = allVehicle.begin(); 
     it != std::prev(allVehicle.end());
     ++it)
```

However there is no need to call `get_the_real_time` twice for each element in the list. You need to call it only once per element:

```
auto it = allVehicle.begin();
auto prev_time = get_the_real_time(it->second->get_date(), it->second->get_time_in());
++it;

for (  ; it != allVehicle.end(); ++it) {
    auto current_time = get_the_real_time(it->second->get_date(), it->second->get_time_in());
    // do something with current_time and prev_time
    prev_time = current_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a segmentation is that you iterate past the end of the list.

Solution: Iterate before the starting the loop, and access step back instead when accessing the first element.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/dh5q5MW34)

(I have added code just to make it compile)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct Vehicle {
    auto get_time_in() {
        return 0;
    }

    auto get_date() {
        return 0;
    }

};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto get_the_real_time = [](auto x, auto y) {
        return time_t{0};
    };

    auto allVehicles = list<pair<string, Vehicle*>>{
        {"hello", new Vehicle{}}, // Don't handle raw data this way
        {"there", new Vehicle{}}, // Its only for the example code
    };

    if (allVehicles.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Solution, iterate before entering the loop
    for (auto it = next(allVehicles.begin(), 1); it != allVehicles.end(); ++it) {
        auto prev_it = prev(it);
        time_t time1 = get_the_real_time(prev_it->second->get_date(), prev_it->second->get_time_in());
        cout << time1 << endl;

        time_t time2 = get_the_real_time(it->second->get_date(), it->second->get_time_in());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to traverse the last element of the list, could you fix that?

Comment: I dont think i understand your algorithm. If thought you wanted to compare two elements to eachother. If you traverse the last element, there is nothing to compare to?

If you want to do something only to the last element, the easiest way is to put it outside the loop.

Comment: @ReyJust Does it work? Did you find a solution?